# Combobox will not show the right item

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have used a combobox with items from a tabel from MySql which works fine. I can pick an item and save an object and the chosen object is shown. But if the user wants to edit the content I can't get the combobox to show the chosen item in the edit-window. The textboxes work fine but the combobox shows the first one in the list and not the selected item.
My constructor:

```
    public CreateForm(Letter brev)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.brev = brev;
        GetDropDownBoxReady();
        saveButton.Visible = false;
        deleteButton.Visible = false;
        insertText(brev);
    }    

    private void GetDropDownBoxReady()
    {
        fraByCB.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        fraByCB.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        fraByCB.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        fraOmraadeCB.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        fraOmraadeCB.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        fraOmraadeCB.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
    } 

    public void insertText(Letter brev)
    {
        // these work fine
        objekt1textBox.Text = brev.Object1;
        objekt2TextBox.Text = brev.Object2;
        diverse2TextBox.Text = brev.Diverse2;
        portoTakstTextBox.Text = brev.PortoTakst;
        portoTillægTextBox.Text = brev.PortoTillaeg;
        portoFraTextBox.Text = brev.PortoFra.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        portoTilTextBox.Text = brev.PortoTil.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        // these don't
        fraByCB.SelectedText = brev.FraBy;

        fraOmraadeCB.SelectedItem = fraOmraadeCB.FindStringExact(brev.FraOmraade);
   }
```

Let me know if you need more of the code too find the problem.

Comment: From your code above the DataSource of the combobox is not set. So it cannot show anything in the dropdown because there is no item to choose from.

Comment: But the combobox work fine, if I click on the arrow the items will be shown. the problem is that it don't set the item I want to show.
Is there some other code you would like to see?

Answer (score 0):

You says that you could see the Items in the combobox dropdown but there is no code shown above that fills the dropdown. Then, probably, you fill the Items property of the combobox with strings in the InitializeComponent call with predefined strings (Using the WinForms designer).

At this point the error is in the insertText method:

```
 fraByCB.SelectedIndex = fraByCB.FindStringExact(brev.FraBy);
 fraOmraadeCB.SelectedIndex = fraOmraadeCB.FindStringExact(brev.FraOmraade);
```

[FindStringExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the position of the item searched if it is found, you could use this value to set the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the combos

So your actual code contains two erros. The first is about the [fraByCB.SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx). This method is used to get/set the highlight on some or all of the text portion of the combo, not to select an intem. The second error is the assignement of the return value of FindStringExact (an integer) to the SelectedItem property that wants the string instead

Comment: I have used the form and data binding to get items in the combobox.